# Print data grid view skips the first row

Tags: mysql, vb.net, print-preview, qprintpreviewdialog

I have created a print preview for the data grid view that I want to print. The code works fine but there is slight problem

Problem Screenshot:[image: Print screenshot]

In the data grid view row, the ID 1 is missing, it always starts from 2. How can I solve this problem? Please help.

My code:

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim mRow As Integer = 0
    Dim newpage As Boolean = True
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True

    With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells

                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rows(0) is the first data row, not header row, while cell.RowIndex is 1, so change rows(cell.RowIndex) as rows(cell.RowIndex-1) :

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `If (newpage)` causes it to draw the headers instead of the first row.

You could change the section

```vb
newpage = False
y += h
mRow += 1
```

to

```vb
If not newpage Then
    mRow += 1
End If
newpage = False
y += h
```

Answer (score 0):

Print each part separately to avoid this kind of problems. The headers part belongs to the [`Columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) collection then print it first before you handle the `Rows` and `Cells` parts.

You have another problem in your code to fix. The `mRow` is a *local* variable that does not preserve the last printed row to skip or the new row to continue with when you request a new page. It must be a *class* field.

```vb
Private mRow As Integer

Private Sub PrintPreviewButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    mRow = 0

    Using d = New PrintPreviewDialog With {
        .Document = PrintDocument1
    }
        d.ShowDialog(Me)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) _
    Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim g = e.Graphics
    Dim x As Integer = e.MarginBounds.X
    Dim y As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Y

    With DataGridView1
        Using sf = New StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic) With {
        .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        }
            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In .Columns
                Dim rect = New Rectangle(
                    x, y,
                    col.Width, col.DataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight)

                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
                rect.Inflate(-3, 0)
                g.DrawString(col.HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)

                x += col.Width
            Next

            y += .ColumnHeadersHeight

            For i = mRow To .RowCount - 1
                Dim row = .Rows(i)

                If row.IsNewRow Then Exit Sub

                x = e.MarginBounds.X

                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    Dim rect = New Rectangle(New Point(x, y), cell.Size)

                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
                    rect.Inflate(-3, 0)
                    g.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString(),
                                    .Font, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)

                    x += cell.Size.Width
                Next cell

                y += row.Height

                If y + row.Height > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                    mRow = i + 1
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End Using
    End With
End Sub
```